# Linux UDP Server unreachable from Window 7

Tags: c++, udp, client-server

I have the following configuration for my experiment.

1. Wifi(Belkin) router connected to Internet.
2. Laptop with Windows 7 OS
3. Laptop with Ubuntu OS.

Experiment: When I connect both of my laptop to Wifi router it assigns DHCP IPs 192.168.2.2 to Linux & 192.168.2.3 to Win 7. Both of them can browse internet. 
              I start a UDP server on my Linux machine with the following code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sd, rc, n, cliLen, flags;
    struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, servAddr;
    char msg[MAX_MSG];

    //Create a socket
    sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd<0){ printf("%s: cannot open socket \n",argv[0]); exit(1); }

    //Bind now to a port
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.2");
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    rc = bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));
    if(rc<0) {printf("%s: cannot bind port number %d \n", argv[0], 9999);exit(1);}

    //We are done ... Notify User
    printf("%s: waiting for data on port UDP %u\n",argv[0],LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);

    //Server's Infinite Loop
    while(1)
    {
            memset(msg,0x0,MAX_MSG);//Sanity
            /* receive message */
            cliLen = sizeof(cliAddr);
            n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, flags,(struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, (socklen_t * )&cliLen);

            if(n<0){printf("%s: cannot receive data \n",argv[0]);continue;}

            //Received message
            printf("%s: from %s:UDP%u : %s \n", argv[0],inet_ntoa(cliAddr.sin_addr),ntohs(cliAddr.sin_port),msg);

            sleep(1);

            //Sending back the data thus received
            sendto(sd,msg,n,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&cliAddr,cliLen);

    }//while
    return 0;
}
```

This code work well & I can receive the packet to the server when some local client on the Linux machine tries to contact my server.

PROBLEM : When I make the same client in Android AVD present in my windows 7 system I am unable to reach my server.

I thought may be that's firewall issue, so I removed the firewall & added by pass custom rules to the IP "192.168.2.2" as given in the following link. http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/40014.aspx#
But it did not work.  I thought that first I should try with raw java first then with AVD. 
Hence, I created a UDP client with Java code still I was not able to connect to server.

Then I thought let's try with raw C++ so that I would come to know exactly what is the problem. Following is the Visual Studio code which I implemented for the same.

```
#define  PORT_NUM       9999            // Port number used
#define  IP_ADDR        "192.168.2.2"   // IP address of server1 
#define  BUFFER_SIZE    4096

void main(void){

WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2,2);       // Stuff for WSA functions
WSADATA wsaData;                              // Stuff for WSA functions

int                  client_s;        // Client socket descriptor
struct sockaddr_in   server_addr;     // Server Internet address
int                  addr_len;        // Internet address length
char                 out_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];   // Output buffer for data
char                 in_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];    // Input buffer for data
int                  retcode;         // Return code


// This stuff initializes winsock
WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);


client_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (client_s < 0){ printf("*** ERROR - socket() failed \n"); exit(-1);}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 // Address family to use
server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);           // Port num to use
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDR); // IP address to use

strcpy(out_buf, "Test message from CLIENT to SERVER");

retcode = sendto(client_s, out_buf, (strlen(out_buf) + 1), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

if (retcode < 0){printf("*** ERROR - sendto() failed \n");exit(-1);}

addr_len = sizeof(server_addr);
retcode = recvfrom(client_s, in_buf, sizeof(in_buf), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, &addr_len);

if (retcode < 0){printf("*** ERROR - recvfrom() failed \n");exit(-1);}

printf("Received from server: %s \n", in_buf);

retcode = closesocket(client_s);
if (retcode < 0){ printf("*** ERROR - closesocket() failed \n");exit(-1);}

WSACleanup();
}
```

But it gives me error of destination unreachable.

To find out exactly what is going on at the packet level, I installed "Wireshark", on my ubuntu machine.

My observation is... whenever my windows client executes I get a ICMP message 3 times on the Wireshark having the type 3 message. The detailed analysis of the packet showed that the port is unreachable.

Kindly help me to find out what I am missing here :(.

Comment: use wireshark to debug these kind of problems.

Comment: Test with a wired connection. If the WiFi has high packet loss, your UDP packets would be silently dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the firewall on the linux machine, or adding an exception for the port you are using?

```
sudo ufw disable
```

or use the following to show your iptables firewall rules:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Alex. I think this is what I was missing. Now my C++ & Java client both can communicate with the server. I can proceed with AVD now. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection between the two machines

- ICMP: ping win->lin and back
- TCP: connect SSH, Samba, or even browser if you can run some web server
- UDP: use nc (netcat) utility to test UDP/TCP connection between two machines

If one of these does not work, look for the problem :

Shut down the firewalls on both computers and on the wireless AP, run sniffers on Win and on Lin machines.

If the connection is ok, the you know you have a bug in your program. Start debugging each end against something working - i.e. nc.

Comment: ICMP ping is working for win -> lin was working before as well; I tried after removing the firewall on linux side it is working. Thanks for the help.