# AVD on Windows7 Not able to connect to Linux Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

This pertains to my earlier post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788825/linux-udp-server-unreachable-from-window-7", which has been solved. Now I am moving to my original job of connecting AVD to Linux server.

I am using the following code for connecting to the server

```
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient {

public final static int DesitnationPort = 9999;
private int mCounter;
private DatagramSocket mClientSocket;
private InetAddress mServerIPAddress;
private byte[] mDataBuffer;
private DatagramPacket mSendPacket;
private DatagramPacket mReceivePacket;

//Constructor
public UDPClient() {

    //Time to make the private data good one
    mCounter =1;
    try {
    mServerIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.2");
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Host cannot be resolved :( ");
    }
    System.out.println("Host has been resolved The IP is valid one ");
    try {
    mClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Socket could not be created :( ==> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Socket has been created ");
    String temp = "This is from the Client == To my Dear Sever :) counter = " + mCounter;
    mDataBuffer = temp.getBytes();
    mSendPacket = new DatagramPacket(mDataBuffer, mDataBuffer.length, mServerIPAddress, DesitnationPort);
    System.out.println("Datagram has been made now ");
    System.out.println("Data ==>"+ mSendPacket.getData());
    System.out.println("Data ==>"+ mSendPacket.getPort());
    System.out.println("Data ==>"+ mSendPacket.getSocketAddress());
    System.out.println("Data ==>"+ mSendPacket.getLength());
}

public void SendDataToServer(){

    try {
            if(!mClientSocket.isClosed())   {

                String temp = "This is from the Client == To my Dear Sever :) counter = " + mCounter;
                mDataBuffer = temp.getBytes();
                mSendPacket = new DatagramPacket(mDataBuffer, mDataBuffer.length, mServerIPAddress, DesitnationPort);           
                mClientSocket.send(mSendPacket);
                System.out.println("Send the packet");
                mCounter++;
            }
            else    {

                System.out.println("Socket is closed");
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not send the data :( ==> " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void ReceiveDataFromServer() {

    byte[] tembuff = new byte[1024];
    mReceivePacket = new DatagramPacket(tembuff, tembuff.length);
    try {
            if(!mClientSocket.isClosed())   {

                mClientSocket.receive(mReceivePacket);

            }
            else    {

                System.out.println("Socket is closed");
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not Receive the data :( ");
        return;
    }
        String data = new String(mReceivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println(" Received the Data => " + data);
}
}
```

This code works well when I simply use the class in java program like this :-

```
class TryingWithClient {
public static void main(String a[]) {
    UDPClient mClient = new UDPClient();
    while(true) {
    System.out.println("While Starting");
    mClient.SendDataToServer();
    mClient.ReceiveDataFromServer();
    }
 }
}
```

When I use the same code in AVD project I get a Null pointer exception at the following line :-

```
public void SendDataToServer(){     
    try {
        if(!mClientSocket.isClosed()){ //<==@ this call Null exception occurs
```

After browsing internet & android development sites I came to conclusion that I am missing the GMS / GPS functionality which I added to my AVD. Still I am unable to get any clue about this.

Here is my code which calls the above UDPClient.

```
public class StreamingProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//All buttons
//private static final String LOG_TAG = "StreamingTest";    
private StreamButton mStreamButton = null;
private UDPClient mClient= null;

class StreamButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartStreaming = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onStream(mStartStreaming);
            if (mStartStreaming) {
                setText("Stop Streaming");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartStreaming = !mStartStreaming;
        }
    };

    public StreamButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start Streaming");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}//class StreamButton Ends

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    try {

        mClient = new UDPClient();
        System.out.println("==========> Client created sucessfully :) <====== ");

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mStreamButton  = new StreamButton(this);
        ll.addView(mStreamButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));

        setContentView(ll);
        System.out.println("Trying Step 2 now ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Activity could not be launched :( ");   
}

}

//public StreamingTest()
public StreamingProjectActivity(){
System.out.println("Constructor ====>");
System.out.println("Constructor <====");
}//Constructor

private void onStream(boolean start) {
    if (start)
    {
        mClient.SendDataToServer();
        mClient.ReceiveDataFromServer();
        try
          {
            Thread.sleep(4000);  

          }catch (InterruptedException ie)
          {
              System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
          }

    }
 }//onStream
}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my earlier solution was that I was mixing the GUI & network operations in  the same thread which is called "StricMode.ThreadPolicy" (although, my problem is only part of what is mentioned in the jargon).

I was getting these exceptions "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException & android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099) " which I could make out only after I applied WarrenFaith's suggestion (Thanks Warren).

These are thrown only on violation of "StricMode".

Solution : Simply separate the UI work from the network. I had to write the following code for this :

```
enum ClientThreadStates {
eUndefined,
eStopped,
eRunning,
eIdle,
eSendToServer,
eReadFromServer
}

public class ClientThread extends Thread {

private UDPClient mClient= null;
private ClientThreadStates mStateOfTheThread = ClientThreadStates.eUndefined;
private static String mLOG_TAG; 

public ClientThread(String s){

    mLOG_TAG = s;
    mStateOfTheThread = ClientThreadStates.eStopped;
    mClient = new UDPClient(s);
    start();
}//constructor

public void SetState(ClientThreadStates paramState) {

    mStateOfTheThread = paramState;
}

public ClientThreadStates GetState() {

    return mStateOfTheThread;
}
private void Action(ClientThreadStates s) {

    synchronized(s) {

        switch(mStateOfTheThread)   {

        case eRunning: //fall
        case eIdle: break;
        case eSendToServer: mClient.SendDataToServer(); break;
        case eReadFromServer: mClient.ReceiveDataFromServer(); break;

        }
        try {
            mStateOfTheThread.wait();
        }
        catch( InterruptedException e ){
            Log.e(mLOG_TAG, "Got Exception at wait <==", e);
        }           

    }
}

public void run() {
    mStateOfTheThread = ClientThreadStates.eRunning;
    System.out.println("In Thread.run .. The State is " + mStateOfTheThread);
    while(ClientThreadStates.eStopped.compareTo(mStateOfTheThread) < 0){ //state >stopped

        Action(mStateOfTheThread);
    }//while

}//run
}//class ClientThread
```

Finally synchronize on the two threads on the state like this :

```
private void onStream(boolean start) {

    ClientThreadStates State = mClientThread.GetState();
    synchronized(State) {
        if (start)  {
            mClientThread.SetState(ClientThreadStates.eSendToServer);
        }
        else        {
            mClientThread.SetState(ClientThreadStates.eReadFromServer);
        }
        try {               
            State.notify();
        }
        catch( IllegalMonitorStateException  e ) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Got Exception @ notify <==", e);
        }        
    }
 }//onStream

}//StreamingProjectActivity
```

Now the code runs perfectly.

Thanks.
Ashutosh

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all: never ever print a catched exception with `System.out.println("some msg " + e.getMessage());` Please use `Log.e(TAG, "my message", e);` for that. So you will actually see a stack trace.

Second: I bet that this code throws an error (check if you see the print in your LogCat output):

```
try {
    mClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
} catch(SocketException e) {
    System.out.println("Socket could not be created :( ==> " + e.getMessage());
}
```

That is the only reason that `mClientSocket` still might be null. As this call might go wrong, you should consider checking for null before you check if the socket is closed.

Comment: Thanks Faith for the guidance.
I applied you suggestion which actually yielded me the cause of the problem.
The problem is occurring in the send call & after analysis of the exception/googling for the solution,
I found the cause to be "StrictMode.ThreadPolicy" define here:=> "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html";
The solution for this could be found here:=> http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html;
Although I did not use the AsyncTask defined there but I managed to separate the threads & its working as expected.